# PyQt4 GUI Box Layout Fixed Width

Tags: python, layout, pyqt4, spacing

Is there a way to set a fixed width of a `QHBoxLayout`?

For example, when I have two small widgets in it that take up little space and I don't want the two to split over the entire screen width when I full screen the app. The widgets already have their widths set to their `minimumSizeHint()` widths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a stretchable space to the end of the layout:

```
    hbox_layout.addStretch()
```

Or if you want the widgets on the right:

```
    hbox_layout.insertStretch(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Admission: I don't use PyQT, but I use Qt in C++. I believe it would work the same.

The trick here, is to as you run QHBoxLayout::addWidget(), you define a stretch factor (greater than zero) to the widgets you want to stretch. You define a zero-stretch factor (the default) to the ones you want to stay small.

Have you run QWidget::setMaximumWidth() on the smallish widgets? That would also be useful, perhaps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this didn't seem to work for me. The problem is not that the Widgets themselves stretch over the screen, they do stay the desired size. The problem is that one of them is on the left side of the screen and one of them is on the right side, very far apart when the app is full screened. I want them to somehow stay close to each other and not split so much apart when the window is enlarged.

Comment: You can use the stretch factor to get this effect. It sounds as if you could, when you add widgets, to define a non-zero stretch factor for all widgets. You'll define stretch factors of 1,2,1, perhaps.Or set a maximum-width on the center widget.